# How to Box Plot Panda Timestamp series ? (Errors with Timestamp type)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, timestamp, seaborn, boxplot

I'm using:

Pandas version 0.23.0

Python version 3.6.5

Seaborn version 0.81.1

I'd like a Box Plot of a column of Timestamp data. My dataframe is not a time series, the index is just an integer but I have created a column of Timestamp data using:

```
# create a new column of time stamps corresponding to EVENT_DTM
data['EVENT_DTM_TS'] =pd.to_datetime(data.EVENT_DTM, errors='coerce')
```

I filter out all NaT values resulting from coerce.

```
dt_filtered_time = data[~data.EVENT_DTM_TS.isnull()]
```

At this point my data looks good and I can confirm the type of the EVENT_DM_TS column is Timestamp with no invalid values.

Finally to generate the single variable box plot I invoke:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x=dt_filtered_time.EVENT_DTM_TS)
```

and get the error:

> TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('M8[ns]') and dtype( 'M8[ns]')

I've Googled and found:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13844
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9610

which seemingly indicate issues with data type representations.

I've also seen references to issues with pandas version 0.21.0.

Anyone have an easy fix suggestion or do I need to use a different data type to plot the box plot.  I'd like to get the single picture of the distribution of the timestamp data.

Comment: You should always be able to plot using numbers. I.e. convert the timestamps to floats (meaning e.g. seconds), and tick the axes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I ended up with:

```
import time
@plt.FuncFormatter
def convert_to_date_string(x,pos):
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m',time.localtime(x))


plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))
sns.set(style='whitegrid')
temp = dt_filtered_time.EVENT_DTM_TS.astype(np.int64)/1E9
ax = sns.boxplot(x=temp)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(convert_to_date_string)
```

Here is the result:

[image: Box plot of times]

*Credit goes to ImportanceOfBeingErnest whose [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746733/how-to-box-plot-panda-timestamp-series-errors-with-timestamp-type#comment92418614_52746733) pointed me towards this solution.*